# Modify the value of a TextBlock in a Timer

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't modify my textBlock in a Timer.

Here is my code:

```
    private void Play_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(displayTime);
            timer.Enabled = true;
            try
            {
               // video.Play();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error: " + exp.Message);
            }
        }
     }

    private void displayTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        textProgression.Text = "Test";
    }
```

Every second, my function displayTime is called but the value of textProgression is not changed.

Comment: Every time `displayTime` is called it sets the text to `"Test"`, so why would you expect the text to change?

Comment: Use `DispatcherTimer` instead.

Comment: @AlvinWong Why should it be a `TextBox`?

Comment: Instead of "Test", I will put the value of the timer. I just used "Test" to simplify my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Any modification you do to the UI in WPF must be done in the WPF Thread (Dispatcher thread).

For this you have two options:

Use the thread, and in displayTime invoke textProgression.Text = "Test"; in the Dispatcher:

```
private void displayTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        textProgression.Text = "Test";
    }));
}
```

Or, the best method here I assume, use a [`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx). Because in this timer, all `Tick` events are fired in the Dispatcher thread.

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textProgression.Text = "Test";
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys, using a DispatcherTimer instead of a simple timer solved my problem :)